# SAP UI5 - Not able to select more than one Check box in Table column

Tags: hana, sapui5

I have created a table with few columns getting data from Odata and i have created another column will have just check box.

My Code is

```
var oTable = new sap.ui.table.Table("Brand",{
                        title: "Brand List",
                    //  visibleRowCount: 10,
                        //firstVisibleRow: 3,
                        selectionMode: sap.ui.table.SelectionMode.None,
                     navigationMode: sap.ui.table.NavigationMode.Paginator,
                        fixedColumnCount: 10,
                        width:"700px"

                    }); 

  oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
                    //  visible: false,
                        label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Country"}),
               template: new  sap.ui.commons.TextView().bindProperty("text", "COUNTRY_ID"),
                        sortProperty: "COUNTRY_ID",
                        filterProperty: "COUNTRY_ID",
                        flexible : false,
                        width:"1px"
                    }));

                    //Define the columns and the control templates to be used
                    oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
                        label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Brand"}),
                        template: new sap.ui.commons.TextView().bindProperty("text", "BRAND"),
                        sortProperty: "CUSTOMER",
                        filterProperty: "CUSTOMER",
                        width:"250px"
                    }));

oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
                        label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "2013",textAlign:"Center"}),
                        template: new sap.ui.commons.CheckBox().bindProperty("checked","checked"),
                        sortProperty: "checked",
                        filterProperty: "checked",
                        width: "100px",
                        hAlign: "Center"
                    }));
```

It works fine when the table length is 10 ( defined in the table creation statement). But if my brand list is more than 10 ( some times it can be more than 100) , still the no. of check boxes is created is 10. so in the table if go to next page (paginator mode ) , the check boxes are still the same.

So if i select a brand in first page and select a brand in third page , the check box remains same. Its not creating check boxes except for the first page.

Please help me on this issue.

Thanks
Sathish

Answer (score 1):

Attempt 2. This time, I'll try answer the question. Sathish, it appears as though your model does not account for the checkbox property. Your OData service is returned data to you (using JSON notation for simplicity) like this:

```
   data : [{
      "COUNTRY_ID" : "USA",
      "BRAND" : "Nike"
    },{ 
      "COUNTRY_ID" : "GER",
      "BRAND" : "Adidas"
    },{ 
      "COUNTRY_ID" : "ITA",
      "BRAND" : "Lotto"
    }]
```

But you are using the returned model as if there is a third property in each object, named 'checked'. E.g.

```
   data : [{
      "COUNTRY_ID" : "USA",
      "BRAND" : "Nike",
      "checked" : false
    },{ 
      "COUNTRY_ID" : "GER",
      "BRAND" : "Adidas",
      "checked" : false
    },{ 
      "COUNTRY_ID" : "ITA",
      "BRAND" : "Lotto",
      "checked" : false
    }]
```

If this property is not part of the model, then you effectively have nothing to bind your checkbox to. Because the property does not exist in the model, the check box column is not bound to anything. When the table is initialised to 10 rows, that is the number of checkbox controls you've created, no more. Once you begin paginating, the number rows never changes, but the pagination binds the next 10 rows of your OData dataset to the table rows and columns. Because the dataset doesn't contain the property 'checked' (my assumption), the column listing the checkboxes is not *rebound* to the model's data, thus the checked checkboxes never change.

I would suggest you do one of two things - update the OData service to include this additional property (checked), and bind the checkbox column to that property, or two, copy the model data to a new model, add the 'checked' property to each object in the collection, and then bind your table to this new model. Either way, you need to ensure that the model has a property to which you can bind the checkboxes.

This link to an editable Table control demonstrates the principal I'm referring to:
[Editable Table control](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-57632)
In this example, the author is making a table editable by using the 'editable' property in each object in his collection. This property, which exists **for every entry in the model's data**, is bound to the TextField control in the table's second column.

```
template: new sap.ui.commons.TextField({  
   value: '{lname}',  
   editable: '{edit}' // Binding editable property of text field to 'edit' attribute of Model   
}),
```

You'll need to do something very similar, but for the Checkbox, **ensuring** the model has a property to bind to.

Good luck.

Comment: This should have been a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Until then, please do not use answers as a workaround.

Comment: Answer rewritten - I *think* it's an answer now.